# Can a SHA3 engine be used to construct a Keccak implementation?

Tags: sha-3, keccak

I am working on a cSHAKE-128 & cSHAKE-256 implementation that takes advantage of a number of hardware accelerators I have at my disposal, specifically for SHA-3 256/384/512 and SHAKE 128/256.

cSHAKE 128 is defined as follows:

```
1. If N = "" and S = "":
return SHAKE128(X, L);
2. Else:
return KECCAK[256](bytepad(encode_string(N) || encode_string(S), 168) || X || 00, L).
```

If condition 1 is met, the solution is trivial, since I do have a SHAKE128 engine available.

However, in the case of condition 2, I don't have a Keccak engine readily available. I'm wondering if SHA3 can be used as primitive to construct Keccak 256.

I have read that SHA3 is directly derived from Keccak (was a result of a contest which Keccak won), but I've also read they're not exactly the same. [This very useful on-line hasher](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) does not produce the same hash values for SHA3 256 and Keccak 256.

Comment: See page 28 https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf and see that none of the SHA3-x is using the KECCAK[256],  extract the sponge construction and base keccak from the SHA3 then you get the base to construct all!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm reading through the document and am trying to understand, but I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with cryptography. I can see this correspondence: SHA3-256(M) = KECCAK[512](M || 01, 256). Let's say I want to hash string 'N' using Keccak-512. Is it possible to achieve this: my_keccak_func(sha3-256_func(), N) = KECCAK-256(N)? Keep in mind one of the restrictions is I cannot modify in any way the SHA3 function, which is given to me as a black box function.

Comment: Only if $M$ ends in the bits $01$ you can strip these bits from the end of $M$ and send the remaining part to SHA3. For other messages, I'm afraid, there won't be a solution.

Comment: At this point, my question would be: why does this NIST document (https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf) refer to cSHAKE128/256 as SHA-3 derived functions, if SHA-3 cannot be used as building block for cSHAKE?

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding about "derived" here. Derivation doesn't preclude alteration and it certainly doesn't necessarily mean that the function needs to be a primitive within the derived function. In other words, I don't think that "derived" as used by NIST is the same "derived" as used for mathematical constructions.

Comment: @ismarlowe Out of curiosity: which device are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Let first look at  $$\operatorname{KECCAK}[c] (N || suffix, d) \label{1}\tag{1}$$ It calls

$$\operatorname{KECCAK}[c] (N, d) = \operatorname{SPONGE}[\operatorname{KECCAK-p}[1600, 24], pad10*1, 1600 – c] (N, d).$$

- $c$ is the capacity
- $d$ is the output size
- 1600 is the base $b$
- $pad10*1$ is the multi rate padding.
- 24 is the number of rounds $n_r$
- The sponge in short is the framework for specifying functions on binary data with arbitrary output length.

---

Let assume that we have a black box SHA3 implementation of any mode

- $\operatorname{SHA3-224}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[448] (M || 01, 224)$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-256}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[512] (M || 01, 256)$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-384}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[768] (M || 01, 384)$
- $\operatorname{SHA3-512}(M) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[1024] (M || 01, 512)$

and black box SHAKEx implementations

- $\operatorname{SHAKE128}(M, d) = \operatorname{RawSHAKE128}(M || 11, d)$
- $\operatorname{SHAKE256}(M, d) = \operatorname{RawSHAKE256}(M || 11, d)$

  where

  - $\operatorname{RawSHAKE128}(J, d) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[256] (J || 11, d)$
  - $\operatorname{RawSHAKE256}(J, d) = \operatorname{KECCAK}[512] (J || 11, d)$

Now you want to use the above as black box implementation for [cSHAKE](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf)

```
 cSHAKE128(X, L, N, S):
 1. If N = "" and S = "":
    return SHAKE128(X, L);
 2. Else:
     return KECCAK[256](bytepad(encode_string(N) || encode_string(S), 168) || X || 00, L).
```

- The `if` part is not a problem, since it directly uses the SHAKE128.
- The `else` part is the problematic part. One can externally implement `bytepad(encode_string(N) || encode_string(S), 168)` and concatenate it with `X`. The domain separation padding `00` is the real issue. I**f the block box doesn't allow this as input, then there is no way to this.**

If the library somehow extendible one may use the \ref{1} to generate all of the above, otherwise no.

The cSHAKE is the base for [KMAC, TupleHash, and ParallelHash.](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf) If you are going to need those, you may need to implement yourself.